# jQuery UI Tooltip widget leave unwanted markup

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

when I call the Tooltip widget of jQuery UI in this way http://jsfiddle.net/xvMBU/5/ and on hover when tooltip hides not all of its html is removed from the page - this is left behind:

```
<div class="ui-effects-wrapper" style="font-size: 100%; background-color: transparent; border: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 64px; height: 42px; float: none; position: absolute; z-index: 9999; top: -11px; left: 0px; bottom: auto; right: auto; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></div>
```

I try this in Chrome and FF v18.0.1. I forgot to mention that this happens when you do it fast.

Comment: The fiddle seems not working... Can you update the working fiddle. Also, specify your browser and OS...

Comment: I tried your fiddle on Firefox 18.0.1 (after removing the `position` option that made the tooltip display outside of the viewport) and the tooltip's additional elements are correctly removed. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Hi @PraveenKumar, try now to open fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, I am using Chrome and nothing is left behind in the view. But do you say that those things are left behind in the code? Those things you wanna clear?

Comment: Actually in the [original site](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) - if this is the one, it clears it, unlike the fiddle. :)

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/xvMBU/25/)**

```
$('#myTooltip').tooltip({
    "items": "#myTooltip",
        "tooltipClass": "gr-t-tooltip-balloon",
    content: function () {
        return "dddd";
    },
        "position": {
        "my": "right top",
            "at": "left"
    },
        "show": {
        "effect": "drop",
            "duration": 150,
            "direction": "left"
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
        $('div.ui-effects-wrapper').remove();  // Add a close function to remove the wrapper.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `close` to `false`.

```
"close": false,
```

Change your code to this:

```
$('#myTooltip').tooltip({
    "items": "#myTooltip",
    "tooltipClass": "gr-t-tooltip-balloon",
    "close": false,
    content: function () {
        return true;
    },
    "position": {
        "my": "right top",
        "at": "left"
    },
    "show": {
        "effect": "drop",
        "duration": 150,
        "direction": "left"
    }
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xvMBU/6/

Comment: sorry but it is not the solution, because when you go fast over the "Hover" text this `<div id="ui-effects-wrapper" ... ></div>` stays in the code after the tooltip is already hide.

Comment: Yeah, just now checked. It seems to be a bug with the jQuery UI framework itself.